# Adding values to individual attributes of Backbone Model

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

Suppose I have a JSON file which contains a number of attributes like this:

```
json.type[1].next_type[1].attribute
```

And I want to change a specific value of a backbone model which is to contain these attributes.

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults:{
    attr1: null,
    attr2: null,
    attr3: null }
```

How would I make `attr1 = json.type[1].new_type[2].attr1` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var m = new M({ attr1: json.type[1].new_type[2].attr1 });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the json file when the model is constructed, you could do

```
var m = new M({'attr1': json.type[1].new_type[2].attr1})
```

otherwise

```
var m = new M()
m.set({'attr1': json.type[1].new_type[2].attr1});
```

should work